# Ionic4 camera plugin - cordova not avaliable on device?

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic4

I am working on an Ionic4 app which needs to be able to take a photo.
I added "cordova-plugin-camera". When i run a function of this plugin on real **DEVICE** to take photo, i get an error "cordova_not_avaliable".
(Note that **OTHER** native cordova plugins work just **fine** - even in same page / module).

I followed basic installation process on Ionic documentation for "cordova-plugin-camera". No other errors are thrown.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-picture',
  templateUrl: './picture.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./picture.page.scss'],
})

export class PicturePage implements OnInit {

  options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
  }

constructor(private camera: Camera) { } 
ngOnInit() {}

takePicture() {
    this.camera.getPicture(this.options).then((imageData) => {
      let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      // this.presentAlert('success');
    }, (err) => {
      // this.presentAlert(err); // Displays "cordova_not_avaliable"
      // (For show on DEVICE. I know rest logic of alert is missing)
    });
  }
}
```

I would expect that cordova **IS** avaliable since it is running on an android Device. No other error is present (Also note that I get an exact same result on ionic serve).

Edit: "Also note i am not very experienced yet in this environments so i might be missing something obvious."

Edit: "title (removed preview)"

Comment: What about your setup code in `app.component.ts` - do you have it setup in there? You are supposed to use `this.platform.ready().then(() => { /*cordova code here*/ })` to make sure that cordova is available before you use anything.

Comment: In app component i have not changed anything yet since basic ionic blank install project.  `this.platform.ready().then(() => { const test = this.platform.is('cordova'); }` EDIT: test returns false if that helps.

Comment: Found sollution, In my camera options i was missing a `sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA` That solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution, In my camera options I was missing a

```
sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
```

That solved the problem.